# WP Theme build in Search engine shows post and products instead only products

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on my shop and I ran into a problem that I can't deal with because I miss php knowledge (still learning). The built-in search engine shows lists of posts and products in the results. It doesn't look good, I just want the products and thumbnail view as in the categories. I would prefer not to change the search engine to a different one. Please let me know if changing the code to search.php will allow me to achieve this effect? If so, which elements should be changed to what?

Search.php code:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : global $wp_query; ?>

    <header>
        <h1 class="selleradise_page__title">
            <?php
                printf(
                    /* translators: %s: Search Term. */
                    esc_html( __("Search Results for: %s", "selleradise-lite") ),
                    '<em>' . get_search_query() . '</em>'
                );
            ?>
        </h1>
    </header><!-- .page-header -->

    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php

        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/search');

        endwhile;
        
            
        if($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1): ?>

            <div class="selleradise_pagination">

                <?php
                    $args = [
                        'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                        'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                        'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
                        'show_all'  => false,
                        'type'      => 'array',
                        'end_size'  => 0,
                        'mid_size'  => 2,
                        'prev_next' => true,
                        'prev_text' => selleradise_svg('unicons-line/angle-left-b'),
                        'next_text' => selleradise_svg('unicons-line/angle-right-b'),
                        'add_args'  => false,
                        'add_fragment' => '',
                        'aria_current' => "page",
                    ];

                    echo paginate_links($args);
                ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif; 

            else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/none');

            endif;
        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: _"Please let me know if changing the code to search.php will allow me to achieve this effect?"_ - probably not in a way that makes much sense. You could of course check at this point, whether the current found item is a normal post or a product - and then simply not create any output for products. But that will mess with how many items you'll see on each page, and the pagination will not make too much sense any more either. The _proper_ way to do this, would be to hook into the search query generation, and exclude the post types you don't want there already.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find where the WP theme sets the `post_type` to both `post` and `product` then that would be better, it could be on the `functions.php` file or something.

If not, then you can try to manipulate the `WP Query` on the `search.php` file, something like this:

```
<?php

// Preserve original wp_query
global $wp_query;
$original_query = $wp_query;

// Assign new query to include only products
$wp_query = null;
$args = array('post_type' => 'product');
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <header>
        ...
    </header>

    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php

        // Start the Loop
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/search');

        endwhile;
        
            
        if($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1): ?>
            ...
        <?php endif; 

else :

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/none');

endif;

    // Reset post query
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $original_query;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</main>
```

Refer to these for [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) and for [resetting postdata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately this solution did not work: (But I found the second file search.php in template-parts and maybe something needs to be changed here, could you please take a look?